# Who is the kingdom of God being taken away from in Matthew 21:43?

Tags: matthew, jesus, covenant

Matthew 21:43 (ESV):

> Therefore I tell you, the kingdom of God will be taken away from you
> and given to a people producing its fruits.

At first glance I would assume he ment the entire nation if Israel, but in v45:

> When the chief priests and the Pharisees heard his parables, they
> perceived that he was speaking about them.

Did Jesus mean the Kingdom of God would be taken away from the entire nation of israel? or specifically those pharisees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether one understand the Jews to be collectively responsible for rejecting Jesus. But in context, it is not the nation or the people generally that Jesus has in mind. In verse 23 of this chapter, it is the leading priests and elders who question Jesus' authority after he disrupted commerce in the Temple. It is also this group that Jesus addresses with both this parable and the preceding one:

> 28 What is your opinion? A man had two sons. He came to the first and
> said, ‘Son, go out and work in the vineyard today...33 Hear another
> parable. There was a landowner who planted a vineyard...

In addition to the what the OP mentions (the leading priests and Pharisees understood the parable to be about them), there is also the fact that the two following chapters are also directed against these groups. In chapter 22, Jesus bemoans the fact that those invited to the wedding feast of the king's son do not come when they are invited. He spars with the Pharisees over the issue of paying taxes to both the Temple and Caesar. He debates the Sadducees over marriage and the resurrection. Although the Pharisees are pleased by his "silencing the Sadducees," he soon criticizes them for their hypocrisy and issues a series of "woes" against them (ch.23).

Jesus' problem in these chapters is not with the people generally. Interestingly, he also upholds the authority of the Pharisees, telling the crowds at the beginning of chapter 23

> Do and observe all things whatsoever they tell you, but do not follow
> their example. For they preach but they do not practice.

But this is followed by the series of "woes" against the Pharisees for their hypocrisy.

**Conclusion**: Jesus' problem in this chapter is not with the people or the nation; it is with their leaders. If we consider this context, the answer must be that the parable mentioned in the OP is targeted against the important priests and elders who rejected Jesus and eventually turned him over the the Romans.  Other scriptures may or may not hold the Jewish nation collectively responsible. But it is not the Jewish nation that this parable is addressed to: it is "the chief priests and elders."

---

NOTE: Mark's account does not name the Pharisees as Jesus' opponents in the parallel account. A note in the NABRE explains: "Matthew inserts into the group of Jewish leaders (Mt 21:23) those who represented the Judaism of his own time."

Comment: The only additional observation I would make is that in the immediate context "therefore" follows on from v42, the quotation of "the stone which the builders rejected". So the declaration applies logically to the loosely defined group "those who reject me". Among whom, of course, the leaders he was addressing had a chief place.

Answer (score 0):

Kingdom of Heaven is believing in Christ's preaching and accepting Him as the only way to the Father (John 14:6) and accepting the Father as the only way to His Son - Christ (John 6:44). Those among Jews, regardless Pharisees, Sadducees, Scribes, other professional theologians, or their followers among plain people who are not professional theologians who do not accept Christ's preaching and continue worshipping God without acknowledging the Incarnation/Inhumanation of His Only-Begotten, pre-eternal Son who alongside with Him created the Universe, yes all those Jews will indeed deprive themselves the Kingdom of Heaven through this very rejection of the King of this Kingdom - Lord Jesus Christ. For how, indeed, can you receive a citizenship in any kingdom without accepting its king? Can one be a citizen of a Roman Empire while not accepting the Emperor?

But those Jews who took Christ as the Son of God and the King of the Eternal Kingdom, they became citizens of this Kingdom, among them also Pharisees, like Paul and other Jewish professional theologians or non-professional-theologians, like the fishermen (Peter, James etc.) or even tax-collectors (Matthew, Zacchaeus). First citizens of the Kingdom were ethnically and historically Jews.

Answer (score 0):

Exodus 19:5-6 refers to the first covenant made by God with the natural  Israelites, Moses told the people of Israel:

The First Covenant:

NASB Exodus 19:5-6

5 Now then, if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My covenant, then you shall be My [a]own possession among all the peoples, for all the earth is Mine; 6 and you shall be to Me a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.’ These are the words that you shall speak to the sons of Israel.”

The natural  Israelites  , and their  religious  leaders the Sadducces and the Pharisees by en-large rejected Jesus. We note that on the day of the Pentecost only a handfull of natural Israelites , about 120  (Acts 1:15) disciples, men and women   in all were present for the   pouring  of God's spirit ,this being  the inauguration of the second covenant (Acts 2:1-4)

The second covenant replaces the first covenant which has become obsolete. (Read the prophesy of Jeremiah 31:31-34)

The second covenant.

Hebrews 8:7-13 NET

7 For if that first covenant had been faultless, no one would have looked for a second one.[a] 8 But[b] showing its fault,[c] God[d] says to them,[e]
“Look, the days are coming, says the Lord, when I will complete a new covenant with the house of Israel and with the house of Judah.
9 “It will not be like the covenant[f] that I made with their fathers, on the day when I took them by the hand to lead them out of Egypt, because they did not continue in my covenant and I had no regard for them,says the Lord.

10 “For this is the covenant that I will establish with the house of Israel after those days, says the Lord. I will put[g] my laws in their minds[h] and I will inscribe them on their hearts. And I will be their God and they will be my people.[i]
11 “And there will be no need at all[j] for each one to teach his countryman or each one to teach his brother saying, ‘Know the Lord,’ since they will all know me, from the least to the greatest.[k]
12 “For I will be merciful toward their evil deeds, and their sins I will remember no longer.”[l]
**13 When he speaks of a new covenant,[m] he makes the first obsolete. Now what is growing obsolete and aging is about to disappear.[n]**

The first covenant is made obsolete by the new covenant, Peter writing to his fellow Christians,  said.

1 Peter 2:9-10 NET

9 But you are a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people of his own, so that you may proclaim the virtues[a] of the one who called you out of darkness into his marvelous light. 10 You[b] once were not a people, but now you are God’s people. You were shown no mercy,[c] but now you have received mercy.

**Conclusion:** The natural Israelites with whom God made the  first covenant, a few months after leaving Egypt, failed to produce a kingdom of priests and a holy nation . Although the nation as a whole failed and the covenant with them cancelled, it did not  prevent individual Israelites from becoming members of the kingdom of God. The new covenint was extented in 36C.E.  to include the Gentiles, with Cornelius being the first uncircumcised to receive the gift of the holy spirit. (Acts 10:24-48)